# Get session variable value

Tags: django, templates, session-variables

After I set a session object, how can I access the value of the given object in my templates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

{{request.session.variable}}

RequestContext will give you access to request object in templates.

You'll have to add this to your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    ... )
```

And to hook up RequestContext to templates you can use this  idiom in the view function:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
return render_to_response('template.html', var_dict,\
      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: OK...thanks so much.  RequestContext will definately be required to access the request object...I had the same problem yesterday

Comment: What if I do not render page, instead it I use HttpResponse, in this case it it not coming

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many session variables you have, it might be easier to just add the variable to the context dictionary.